# Displaying google maps

Tags: android

There is runtime exception and the app crashes, kindly cooperate with me. I would be really thankful to you all for this ! I have used Google Apis 18 emulator and android device 4.1 both. Also imported google play services and using google api v2 and it's option is also ON in key section of gmail.

LogCat,

```
 09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    ... 11 more
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at maps.ag.bb.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at maps.ag.bb.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at maps.ag.an.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at maps.ag.bi.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at maps.ag.bh.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at blf.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh$4.b(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.a(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
 09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):   at     android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
 09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):   at      android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
 09-10 18:37:47.890: E/AndroidRuntime(23014):   ... 21 more
```

Java file,

```
 package com.example.test;
 import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
protected GoogleMap gMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    gMap = ((SupportMapFragment)    
 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
     if (gMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Xml file,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >


   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.test"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <permission
     android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

   <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



   <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCpwkQvt7NFXbprE6QgfT-YQEWWApZ1IDQ" />


        </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: I am stuck since last 15 days with this kind of errors.

Comment: http://twntee.tumblr.com/post/59576020346/the-maps-api-adding-a-map-to-your-android-project follow this blog, i too was stuck so I created this tutorial.

Comment: Gr8 tutorial .......... claps!

Comment: thank you :) i feel happy :), i wish you should have left a comment there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must write following code after `</activity>` tag and before `</application>` tag.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCpwkQvt7NFXbprE6QgfT-YQEWWApZ1IDQ" />
```

Like

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCpwkQvt7NFXbprE6QgfT-YQEWWApZ1IDQ" />
</application>
```

Comment: Another exception:: Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers.
 This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Answer (score 0):

did you even look at the error, it clearly states what is wrong

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.`

you did not put your API key in the right place, it needs to be inside the `application` tag and not the activity tag

Comment: Only white blank tiles are shown ,                                   Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers.
 This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Answer (score 0):

goto https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:522283682873
the goto services and switch on the Google Maps Android API v2 toggle button.

Then it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

After putting the API key in right place and then changing it , this worked for me and now my app is displaying map. I am really thankful to you all!